# Determining Counts of Discrete Objects Using Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices

I'm teaching myself linear algebra and was able to solve the following question using trial and error, but--how would one setup and solve a question like this using Linear Algebra?

> I have 32 bills in my wallet, in the denominations of \$1, \$5, and \$10--worth $100 in total. 
>   How many do I have of each denomination?

Bretscher, Otto (2013-02-21). Linear Algebra with Applications (5th Edition) (Page 8). Pearson HE, Inc.. Kindle Edition.

Trying to solve it myself, I start with three variables, `a`, `b`, and `c`, each denoting the count of a single denomination of bill. ( Specifying units might seem a little pedantic now, but informs part of my question later. Bear with me. )

> $ a \space bills + b \space bills + c \space bills = 32 \space bills $
>
> $ 1 \frac{dollars}{bill} a \space bills + 5 \frac{dollars}{bill} b \space bills + 10 \frac{dollars}{bill} c \space bills = 100 \space dollars $

Canceling units we get:

> $ a \space bills + b \space bills + c \space bills = 32 \space bills $
>
> $ 1a \space dollars + 5b \space dollars + 10c \space dollars = 100 \space dollars $

So, I'm tempted to setup a matrix as follows:

> $
> \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
> 1 \space bills & 1 \space bills & 1 \space bills & 32 \space bills \\
> 1 \space dollars & 5 \space dollars &10 \space dollars & 100 \space dollars
> \end{array}
> \right)
> $

And here we can see the two problems that derail my thought:

1. Can we subtract Equation I from Equation II, given they have different units?
2. Don't we need at least three data points, three pieces of information, in order to solve a system of three variables?

I'm sure the solution is simple, but--I just can't see it.

Comment: In my thought we can't solve it using system of equations cause there are 2 equations and 3 unknowns.

Comment: and you can subtract any of the equation from other one. you are looking at it they have unit but there aren't any(both side of equality you can cancel out unit). they are just numbers and unknowns(which is also numbers).

Comment: @iostream007 - Good call!

Comment: You also know that $a,b,c$ are non-negative integers.

Comment: It seems there is one solution in positive integers, and another in non-negative integers (which may or may not be allowed by the words in the question).